# What is the easiest, most reputable, most seasoned AJAX framework?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jakarta-ee, frameworks

I have dabbled with various AJAX frameworks, namely GWT, Dojo, Ext-JS, jQuery UI.  I am interested in understanding what AJAX frameworks best meet the following criteria:
- Most easy to learn
- Most painless to keep maintained
- Most reputable, stable, founded & grounded
- Easiest to read and share
- Integrates well with J2EE

Comment: You don't even begin to compare GWT to a Javascript framework. Maybe gQuery ;)

Comment: This is sort of like asking what the best programming language is - everyone has their own biases, and different libraries have different strengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery on the client side, DWR on the server side.

Answer (score 7):

why, jQuery of course ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question to answer here, because most Ajax frameworks keep improving, changing, and attracting new users. You never know where the next ultra-large scale Internet site will come from, and if they choose an Ajax framework that rates low here, they are as likely to put the developer hours into fixing it as they are to change frameworks.

So please take the advice on this question with a grain of salt, especially as the question gets older and older. Someone might update the answers or maybe not.